# How to do count(*) from subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I write a count(*) using a subquery?

```
select count(*) from Firms
select count(*) from (select * from Firms)
```

In the above two lines, the top one works, however in the second line, I get the error:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

But isn't `(select * from Firms)` == `Firms`?

**EDIT:**
However for this:

```
select count(*) from 
    (
        select HireResponseID, HireResponse, DateResponse, Comments, YearFileOpened, file_number, isCaseOpen, last_update, isConfidential, date_created, OurClient, TheirClient, ProjectName, description, lawyer_lastname, lawyer_firstname, Conflicts.ConflictID
        from Hire_Response, Conflicts, Lawyers 
        WHERE Hire_Response.ConflictID=Conflicts.ConflictID AND Lawyers.lawyerID=Conflicts.lawyerID AND firmID = @FirmID AND HireID = @HireID AND isStillaConflict = 1 
        ORDER BY  file_number, TheirClient, OurClient, lawyer_lastname, lawyer_firstname
    ) as data
```

I get the error:

```
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Not only is an order by clause invalid in a subquery, it wouldn't accomplish anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an alias on the second version:

```
select count(*) 
from 
(
  select * -- change this to the column names - you shouldn't use select *
  from Firms
) f -- this is missing
```

SQL Server requires an alias on all derived tables and subqueries

Comment: I tried this on my other query, but I get an error. I posted it on my first post above.

Comment: @omega remove the `order by` they are not allowed in subqueries without a `top`